# orgmode - inline image resize not happen

Tags: org-mode

I have installed emacs 25.3.1 ("GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)of 2017-09-26) and Imagemagick-6.8.8 on windows10. when I try below orgmode document (The tiger png file is downloaded [here](http://pngimg.com/uploads/tiger/tiger_PNG550.png):

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 600px
[[./tiger.png]]
```

The displayed image still very small (resize not happen):

[image]
And below variable all nil:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(print org-image-actual-width)
(print (image-type-available-p 'imagemagick))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: nil
: 
: nil
```

Not sure if emacs still support imagemagick!

Answer (score 4):

To see if your Emacs supports imagemagick check the variable `system-configuration-features`. If the value contains the entry IMAGEMAGICK, you should be OK.

In any case, to resize images within org mode you don't set an HTML attribute, but rather an ORG attribute, as in:

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 600px
[[./tiger.png]]
```

You can also specify a default value to image sizes by changing the variable `org-image-actual-width`.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like official release do not include imagemagick feature: my output is: "XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG SOUND NOTIFY ACL GNUTLS LIBXML2 ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS"

Comment: same for me, emacs27 on Ubuntu 18 :/

Comment: okay, got it to work without imagemagick in the feature list. I was trying to set the height ^^

Comment: If you have a babel block, where exactly to you place the #+ATTR_ORG: :width 600px line? Right above #+RESULTS:?

Comment: Directly over the output image. I haven't found a way to have org-babel automatically add the attribute. Maybe ask that as a separate question?